# Flask redirect to url with multiple slashes

Tags: python, flask

I have a flask route like this:

```
@app.route('/foo/<var1>/<var2>')
def foo(var1, var2):
```

And later on, I try to do this:

```
return redirect(url_for('foo/bar/baz'))
```

This gives me

```
werkzeug.routing.BuildError
BuildError: ('foo/bar/baz', {}, None)
```

I've looked around and found no solutions, I've also tried things like

```
return redirect(url_for('foo'), var1='bar', var2='baz')
```

But I get the same error. Can anyone help me figure out how to properly redirect to this route?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

url_for takes the function name as well as keyword arguments.

In your case, `redirect(url_for('foo', var1='bar', var2='baz'))` should work.

Note that what I have provided *is different* than the last example you provided.

Comment: Thanks!!! Never occurred to me that the variables would be inside url_for for whatever reason. I probably stupidly skimmed over or misread documentation.

Comment: Thank you SO much for mentioning that it is the function name that is being passed and NOT the actual route url. I didn't realize this and had such a hard time.figuring out why it wouldn't work with /foo/bar when the function name was foobar